# $\mathsf{Spec} \: A[X]$, with $A$ UFD

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a PID, then it's not too difficult to prove that $\mathsf{Spec} \: A$ is the "same" $^*$ of $\mathsf{Spec \: \mathbb{Z}}$.

Now my question is:

> **Q.** How to prove the same result for $A$ UFD?

$^*$ With the word "the same" I mean that the spectrum is of the following type:

$\bullet$ $\mathfrak{p}=(p)$, where $p\in A$ is irreducible.

$\bullet$ $\mathfrak{p}=(f(X))$, where $f(X)\in A[X]$ is irreducible.

$\bullet$ $\mathfrak{p}=(p,f(X))$, where $p\in A$ is irreducible and $f(X)\in A[X]$ is irreducible $\mathsf{mod} \: p$.

$\bullet$ $\mathfrak{p}=(0)$.

Comment: If $A=\mathbb C[X]$, then the spectrum of $A$ is not quite the same as that of $\mathbb Z$...

Comment: With the same I don't mean homeomorphic. However, now I provide to clarify what I mean.

Comment: Unless you tell us what you mean, it is impossible to guess...

Comment: You are right. I edited the question.

Comment: Think about UFDs like $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as schemes $\text{Spec }A$ and $\text{Spec }\Bbb Z$ are **not**
isomorphic unless $A\cong\Bbb Z$. However their underlying
topological spaces are homeomorphic provided that $A$ is a PID
having countably infinite distinct prime ideals.

But this is no longer the case for more general UFDs. If $A=\Bbb Q[X,Y]$
then $A$ has nontrivial chains of nonzero prime ideals, so as a topological
space, its spectrum is not homeomorphic to that of any PID.